# Hibernate: маппинг полей объекта на колонки таблицы

Tags: java, hibernate, аннотации

Как осуществить подобное отображение?

Например, есть класс `Deposit`, а в нём поле типа `Currency`. Класс `Currency` содержит поле `Amount` типа `long` и поле `Code` типа `String`.

В базе данных в таблице есть две колонки: `money_amount` и `currency`.
Как можно было бы описать это дело при помощи аннотаций?

```
@Column(name = ???)
private Currency currency;
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
@Embeddable
public class Currency {
    @Column(name = "money_amount")
    public long amount;
    @Column(name = "currency")
    public String code;
}

@Entity
public class Deposit {
    @Embedded
    private Currency currency;
}
```